# html font size not working as expected with mpdf

Tags: php, css, mpdf

**$pdf_html** variable are holding html content to add on each pdf pages. The problem is the inline font size not working. If i change it to any large font size number nothing working rather taking a default font size always. please check the below codes.

Is there anything wrong on my html deceleration? any suggestion?

Note: I have to write each html tag as absolute position which is defined on stylesheet but not inline.

```
$defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$storage_path = storage_path();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents($storage_path.'/fonts/style_pdf_custom.css');
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
   'dpi' => 144,
   'tempDir' => $storage_path . '/app/public/documents/completed/pages',
   'fontDir' => array_merge($defaultConfig['fontDir'], [
          $storage_path . '/fonts'
   ]),
   'fontdata' => $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'] + [
          'greatvibes' => [
               'R' => 'GreatVibes-Regular.ttf',
           ],
           'montezregular' => [
               'R' => 'Montez-Regular.ttf',
           ],
           'sacramentoregular' => [
                'R' => 'Sacramento-Regular.ttf',
           ]]            
 ]);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
 foreach($available_documents as $key => $doc){
      $pages = $this->appRepo->getDocumentPages($doc->id, $doc->envelope_id);
      $sourceFilename = $doc->filename_system_generated;
      $mpdf->SetSourceFile($storage_path . "/app/public/documents/" . $sourceFilename);
      foreach($pages as $k => $page){
                $elements = json_decode($page->elements);
                $mpdf->AddPage();
                $importedPage = $mpdf->importPage($page->page_no);
                $mpdf->useTemplate($importedPage, ['adjustPageSize' => true]);
                $pdf_html = '<div class="common-block" style="width:203px;  left:158px;top:243px;height:28px;justify-content: left;color:black;font-size:22px;font-weight: bold;  ">  Mr. Admin</div><div class="common-block" style="width:247px;  left:739px;top:365px;height:40px;justify-content: left;color:black;font-size:24px; ">Checking Font Size</div>';            
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($pdf_html, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);                
        }
 }
 $tempname = time().$filename;
 $mpdf->Output($storage_path. "/app/public/documents/temp/" . $tempname, "F");
```

Comment: Check the created HTML. Easier for you, _and would be easier for us._

Comment: I have faced the same issue, i kept the pdf html, pdf css separate ( used for pdf only ).
The normal html may not match 100% with PDF, you have to do adjustments. also please check [supported tags on mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-tags.html)

Comment: @DCoder Yes i have separated pdf html and css already. My html do not have body tag and i have included the css only one time at first. Could you please tell me how you fix it if possible.

I also have inline css which seems like not working

Comment: @Md.ZiyedUddin Noone can help you unless you also _share_ your actual code. Hint: learn what MCVE is.

Comment: @Md. Ziyed Uddin I did not use position absolute : since each absolute element was relative to the document and some css was not effective there. My entire page was <div> and <table>, and sometime nested table.

Comment: @DCoder, I just checked that when i set to position relative the font size is working but when i set it to position absolute font size totally not working. But i have to keep position absolute as application requirement design match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing research last couple of days i can figure out the problem why the font size not working properly inside a div with absolute position.

When your html content have absolute position and you have set a fixed height, width then what ever font-size you set it will not exceed the div and mpdf auto adjust the font-size but while on relative position any font-size always works as it define.

So finally i have adjust the div **width** and **height** then i found the actual font-size changes are working well on a div with **position:absolute**

Comment: It would be nice to see what you did: with position:absolute, you at least need width:100% ?